# Prove that a Truncated Gaussian is log-concave

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, gaussian

Is the truncated Gaussian a log-concave distribution?

I read [here](https://econwpa.ub.uni-muenchen.de/econ-wp/game/papers/9611/9611002.pdf) at Section 2.2.5 that whatever log-concave truncated distribution (and hence also Gaussian) is log-concave and the proof is trivial. How to prove this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the density of a truncated rv is the following

$$f_{X|X>c}=\frac{1}{1-F_X(c)}f_X(x)$$

This prove your statement

---

Proof of the truncated density

Let's$X$ a rv (assuming it is continuous) with CDF $F_X(x)$ and let $B=\{X>c\}$

Thus, by definition

$$F(x|B)=\frac{\mathbb{P}[c<X<x]}{\mathbb{P}[X>c]}=\frac{F_X(x)-F_X(c)}{1-F_X(c)}$$

if $x>c$ and zero  if $x\leq c$

derivating F you get the density I showed before

Comment: Can you add more information about why the density of a truncated RV has this form?

Comment: @Apprentice : I added a complete proof